# Does Python have properties?

Tags: python

So something like:

```
vector3.Length
```

that's in fact a function call that calculates the length of the vector, not a variable.

Answer (score 14):

With new-style classes you can use `property()`: http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/#property.

Answer (score 6):

Yes: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property

Answer (score 5):

If your variable *vector3* is a 3-dimensional directed distance of a point from an origin, and you need its length, use something like:

```
import math
vector3 = [5, 6, -7]
print math.sqrt(vector3[0]**2 + vector3[1]**2 + vector3[2]**2)
```

If you need a solution which works for any number of dimensions, do this:

```
import math
vector3 = [5, 6, -7]
print math.sqrt(sum(c ** 2 for c in vector3))
```

You can define your own vector class with the `Length` property like this:

```
import math
class Vector3(object):
  def __init__(self, x, y, z):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.z = z
  @property
  def Length(self):
    return math.sqrt(self.x ** 2 + self.y ** 2 + self.z ** 2)
vector3 = Vector3(5, 6, -7)
print vector3.Length
```

Answer (score 3):

Before the property() decorator came in, the idiom was using a no-parameter method for computed properties. This idiom is still often used in preference to the decorator, though that might be for consistency within a library that started before new-style classes.

Answer (score 0):

you can override some special methods to change how attributes are accesss,
see the python documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access) or  [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#more-attribute-access-for-new-style-classes)

Both these will slow down any attribute access to your class however, so in general using properties is probably best.